Is there a theorem prover that is based on the axioms of ZFC?
Most theorem provers do not use the axioms of ZFC per se, but rather, something like higher-order logic, or type theory. I am interested in whether there is a theorem prover that uses the axioms of ZFC, perhaps paired with either a natural deduction proof system or a Hilbert-style proof system. Is there even such a theorem prover?

This answer has some info on that in its first paragraph: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2168/2946

Metamath.......

Isabelle/ZF, Mizar, etc.

@AlexNelson Mizar is based on TG, which implies ZFC.
